# How to test error codes with swagger and dredd?

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-2.0, dredd

Any Idea how the rest api error codes can be tested with Dredd in combination with swagger .yaml file?

Is there a best practice how to test all the different errors for the paths?

Example:

```
Path /task/{id} can have 3 type of responses: 
200 -> OK
404 -> Task not found 
403 -> Forbidden(not your task)
```

Is it possible to test all 3 "workflows" for this path with swagger / dredd?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with [hooks](https://dredd.org/en/latest/hooks/index.html). See the [Choosing HTTP Transactions](https://dredd.org/en/latest/how-it-works.html#choosing-http-transactions) and [Multiple Requests and Responses](https://dredd.org/en/latest/how-to-guides.html#multiple-requests-and-responses) sections in Dredd's docs:

> When using OpenAPI 2 format, by default Dredd tests only responses with `2xx` status codes. Responses with other codes are marked as skipped and can be activated in hooks:
>
> ```
> var hooks = require('hooks');
>
> hooks.before('/resource > GET > 500 > application/json', function (transaction, done) {
>   transaction.skip = false;
>   done();
> });
> ```